# Exec a shell script when docker run

Tags: docker

I'm trying to execute a shell script during a docker run command:

Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY ./environment.sh /usr/share/nginx/html

RUN chmod +x /usr/share/nginx/html/environment.sh

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY build/ .

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/share/nginx/html/environment.sh"]
```

environment.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "TESTE"
F_MAIN=$(ls main.*.js)
sed -i "s#api.seplan#$API_URL#g" $F_MAIN
sed -i "s#api.eautoriza#$API_URL_AUTORIZA#g" $F_MAIN
```

Docker Run Command

```
sudo docker run --env API_URL=http://192.168.250.212:8084/seplan --env API_URL_AUTORIZA=http://192.168.250.212:8081/eAutorizaService/rest -p 4006:80  msaraujo/1736
```

When I do docker ps it doesn't create it at all and neither script is executed. Why?

Comment: What do you expect the final state to be?  What should be running in the container, and what should be running it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's the whole problem, but

```
COPY ./environment.sh /usr/share/nginx/html
```

is not right.

The [Dockerfile documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) says:

> - `COPY [--chown=<user>:<group>] <src>... <dest>`
>
> [...]
>
> - If `<dest>` does not end with a trailing slash, it will be considered a regular file and the contents of `<src>` will be written at `<dest>`.

So this would attempt to create a regular file called `html` and copy the script into it.

Try

```
COPY ./environment.sh /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

instead.